# Integrating with repsect to x

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given the function

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-u^2} du\right)^2
\end{equation}

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives:

\begin{equation}
f'(x)=2\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-u^2} du\right)e^{-x^2}
\end{equation}

I understand the first part $2\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-u^2} du\right)$ but I cannot understand why we added the second term $e^{-x^2}$. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Hint: Chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $$G(x)=\int_0^x e^{-u^2}\mathrm dx=\int_0^x g(u)\mathrm du.$$ 
You have that $$f(x)=G^2(x).$$
Therefore $f'(x)=2G(x)G'(x)$ and by definition, $G'(x)=g(x)$. I let you conclude.

Comment: Based on fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)= F(b)-F(a)$
So we do not have $f'(x)=2\left(\int_{0}^{x} e^{-u^2} du\right)(e^{-x^2}-1)$?

Comment: Based on fundamental theorem of calculus we indeed have $$\int_a^x f(t)dt=F(x)-F(a).$$ Therefore $$\left(\int_a^x f(t)dt\right)'=(F(x)-F(a))'=F'(x)$$ since $F(a)$ is constant.

Comment: Right I missed the differentiation. Great, now it make sense. Thank you.